# Splice also affecting initial array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to split my array in half and save the results of that in another array, But without affecting the original.

So if I had `[1,3,9,5]` I would want to save it in a variable.
Then I would create new array and copy the initial one in it.
Then I would split that new array in half.

Meaning in the end I would have 2 array like this

> ```
> initial [1,3,9,5]
> halved [1,3]
> ```

The problem is that initial one is also splitted and I get 2 array with each one holding half the values.

```js
var initial = [1,3,9,5];

var half = initial;

half = half.splice(0, Math.floor(half.length / 2));

console.log(initial);
console.log(half);
```

Comment: splice is destructive, slice is not. 
I learned it the hard way.

Comment: Omg. I guess a lot of answers here confused those two. I know I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var half = initial;
```

copies the *reference* of `initial` to `half`. They’re the same array.

Either copy the values of the array with `var half = initial.slice();` or get the half right away with

```
var initial = [1, 3, 9, 5];
var half = initial.slice(0, Math.floor(initial.length / 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

**Option 1** Creating a copy of the initial array

```
var initial = [1,3,9,5];

var half = [].concat(initial);

half = half.splice(0, Math.floor(half.length / 2));

console.log(initial);
console.log(half);
```

The `[].concat(initial)` allows to create a copy of the `initial` array.

**Option 2** Do not modify the initial array, but use `slice` method

```
var initial = [1,3,9,5];

var half = initial.slice(0, Math.floor(half.length / 2));

console.log(initial);
console.log(half);
```

Comment: While your option 1 works... it feels like using a sledge-hammer when a regular hammer (`slice`) is most appropriate. By using `concat + splice`you're essentially mimicking `slice` but in a less efficient way.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel Agreed. The 2 options are showed for a better understanding on the problem. Sure `slice()` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
var initial = [1,3,9,5];

var half = initial.slice(0, Math.floor(initial.length / 2));

console.log(initial); 
console.log(half);
```

Answer (score 1):

When splitting an array there are two prototype methods:

- **splice**: a destructive version which affects the original array.
- **slice**: a pure version, which returns a new array without affecting the array on which it operates.

`var half = initial.slice(0,Math.floor(half.length / 2));`

Just replace your use of **splice** with **slice** and you're good to go.

For more information, I invite you to consult the excellent [MDN document for Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [MDN document for Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var half = initial;` you only pass a reference, not copy an array.
You need to use other method to copy an array, for example:

```
var half = initial.slice();
```